# Align matplotlib Text with colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to align the bottom edge of a `Text()` instance with the bottom edge of a `colorbar` instance, but it's not working the way I expected:

I'm obtaining the colorbar y position using `cb.ax.get_position().ymin`, and then setting my text object's y position like so:

```
cb = plt.colorbar(mappable, shrink=0.5)

details = plt.text(
    1., 1.,
    "Text",
    ha='right', va='bottom',
    size=5,
    color='#555555',
    transform=ax.transAxes,
    fontdict={
        'family': 'Helvetica',
        'size': 6})
details.set_y(cb.ax.get_position().ymin)
```

I've tried altering the `va`, but the two are never aligned: using `va=bottom` the middle of the text appears to be aligned with the middle of the colorbar; using `va=center`, the text box ymin is below the (apparent) cb ymin. What's the best way to get and set the coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How does this look, just directly plot to `cb.ax`:

```
>>> x=linspace(-4,4)
>>> y=linspace(-4,4)
>>> g=meshgrid(x,y)
>>> z=g[0]**2+5*g[1]
>>> ctf=plt.contourf(x, y, z)
>>> cb=plt.colorbar(ctf, shrink=0.5)
>>> cb.ax.text(0.5, 0, 'text', va='top', ha='center')
<matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x9173670>
```

[image]